# Find duplicate values in an array which creates a new array with key as duplicate keys and values as the dupes

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to find all duplicates in my array, and create a new array which has keys as the duplicate values key and value as the key of its duplicate

example

```
[1] => 10
[2] => 11
[3] => 12
[4] => 12
[5] => 12
[6] => 13
[7] => 13
```

After I apply the duplicate check I just need

```
[4] => [3] // value of key 4 is dupe of key 3
[5] => [3] // value of key 5 is dupe of key 3
[7] => [6] // value of key 7 is dupe of key 6
```

this gets me all duplicate keys, but I need duplicate keys with values as the keys which are duplicate

```
$arr_duplicates = array_keys(array_unique( array_diff_assoc( $array, array_unique( $array ) ) ));
```

Thanks

Comment: Wha? I need one million things that are a thing?

Comment: @Neal
sorry its hard to explain what I am trying to explain

Basically I just need to get all dupes as an array but the values of my new array should be the key from which they are dupes of.

Comment: Why did you edit the output format?  You can't have two elements with the same key (`3`).

Comment: @RocketHazmat -  I have added few comments to explain what I need in more details

Comment: @user2619159: You still can't have key `3` equal to both `4` and `5` (unless you make it an array).

Comment: @RocketHazmat sorry stupid mistake from my side, been working since 9am brain is a mush :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for potential speed boost over the other solution. Will however use a lot more memory on large data sets.

```
<?php

$orig = array(
    1   => 10,
    2   => 11,
    3   => 12,
    4   => 12,
    5   => 12,
    6   => 13,
    7   => 13
);

$seen  = array();
$dupes = array();

foreach ($orig as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($seen[$v])) {
        $dupes[$k] = $seen[$v];
    } else {
        $seen[$v] = $k;
    }
}
unset($seen);

var_dump($dupes);
```

Comment: Nice one, thats very fast

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.  Loop over the array, and see if the value was already in there.  If so, add it to the result.

```
$arr_duplicates = array();
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    // array_search returns the 1st location of the element
    $first_index = array_search($v, $array);
    // if our current index is past the "original" index, then it's a dupe
    if($k != $first_index){
        $arr_duplicates[$k] = $first_index;
    }
}
```

DEMO: http://ideone.com/Kj0dUV

Comment: Change `$k > $first_index` to `$k != $first_index` to make it work with indexes in any order, such as `$array = [7 => 13, 6 => 13]`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat this is a great function,
I had tried foreach() before too, the only issue ive had is, am working with very large arrays i.e 10000++ records, and speed is very important

Comment: @user2619159: Anything else you try is probably gonna be slower.  Do you notice a speed issue with this code?  If not, then it's probably not an issue :-P

Comment: Speed can be improved by keeping track of the first time each value was seen. You'd be trading a possible speed boost for an enormous amount of memory usage.

Comment: @Nate: I guess you could cache the `array_search` lookups, that may be faster, but I'm not sure how much.

Comment: Just posted an answer that will not add the slowness of `array_search`, but at the cost of increased memory usage, especially with a large array with many unique values.